# Change orientation in androidx86

Tags: android-x86, android-pc

How can I fully rotate my screen and not only resize it like in the picture?[image]

In already tried several rotation apps in the play store. I tried via **root shell** the commands: `wm size`, `settings put system accelerometer_rotation 0` and `settings put system user_rotation 0` both are working fine on my phone, but not on my tablet.

Answer (score 2):

You should try some rotation control app from play store, like [Rotation Control](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.crape.rotationcontrol) which can rotate the screen in any direction you want (like reverse portrait)
     But you should also note that it's not possible with every app, because maybe the layout is not provided or the layout is forced to be in portrait mode, in that case no app can help you.
    There ain't much apps available specifically for xxhdpi & xxxhdpi screens and so you're not left with much choice but to work with the way it is....

Comment: @Abochur As OP puts, "How can I fully rotate my screen and **not only resize it** like in the picture?" - what I understand from this is, the situation shown in the picture is what OP has right now, and is not what he wanted. I'd say this answer got it right.

Comment: @Abochur On Android-x86 it works differently, since 1) most PCs have a built-in keyboard which is recognized, and Android by default will disable rotation with a keyboard connected (even if auto-rotation is enabled), and 2) many PCs don't have a sensor to detect auto-rotation with in the first place.

Comment: That is exactly what I get when I use such a rotation app you mention. I also tried via shell WM size, and settings put system user_rotation.

Comment: @AndyYan my tablet, has a rotation  sensor. It works on windows but it seems that android does not recognize it. I also detached the keyboard several times to see if that helps but it does not unfortunately.

Comment: Android x86 is not a perfect os for PCs, it has a lot of glitches and this is one of many...

Comment: @DhrubaJyotiSaikia so there is no way that this works? Should o try something like RemixOS (but i think it has been discontinued) or PheonixOS (its not very good).

Comment: If you ask for my suggestion, then I'd say you should go with Linux, that's pretty amazing, and it'll definitely allow you to use your device to its full potential...

Comment: [Rotation Control](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.crape.rotationcontrol) works only properly if in init.sh has_sensors is set to true

Answer (score 0):

I did not found any solution. I installed the new [PhoenixOS](http://www.phoenixos.com/en/download_x86). It works good, and the orientation sensor works too. Maybe we will find a solution for android x86 soon.

Answer (score 0):

In latest version of Android x86_64 8.1 Screen is rotating normally if you select in Grub ... > Advanced Options ... > Vulkan Support

Answer (score 0):

I face same problem on chuwi Hi10 x.
Reason was if your tablet orientation sensor is not recognized 
Or defined in Android it forces screen in one orientation 
To solve this
Open init.sh file which in device root /etc/init.sh
Find the following line
"has_sensors = false" and make it = true
this tell android that you have orientation sensor even if it actually not recognized it
Then reboot
Now you can change orientation using any orientation app.